# set displayed scale of axis in plot?

Tags: netlogo

In the model I'm working on, ticks are months, and line plots are updated once every year, i.e. every 12 ticks.  As ticks accumulate, the scale within the graph changes, of course, and the number in the lower right corner of the plot increases.  This number reflects the number updates that have been made to the plot--i.e. the number of years.  The number is the number of years that can be represented on the plot given its current scale.

Is there a way to change this number, without changing the rest of the plot, and without changing the idea that ticks are months?  It would be convenient for this maximum x-axis value to show the number of months--i.e. ticks that could be displayed, even though the plot is only updated every 12 ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `set-plot-x-range` primitive. http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set-plot-x-range